# Excel Formula not Calculating as Expected (Excel Calculation Chain Breaks)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a custom C# add-in I am using in Excel.

By way of example, when I try use `ActiveSheet.Calculate` there is some "random" behaviour in how Excel calculates the worksheet, and occasionally does not calculate some formulas. However, if I select the cell and use `ActiveCell.Calculate` it calculates it just fine. It seems, for some reason, some cells are being ignored/not being calculated with the worksheet scope `.Calculate` method.

A couple questions for the community:

1. Has anyone seen this behaviour before and how did you solve?
2. Does anyone understand how Excel manages it's volatile nature in how cells are calculated, and so, somehow some cells are not included in a refresh (Shift+F9)?

PS I want to avoid "forcing" these formulas to volatile, i.e. adding an in-built volatile function like `NOW()`, as I have hundreds of formulas. But forcing them like this also fixes the issue.

**EDIT**

After some more research, it seems that Excel's calculation tree seems to break, and so the `.CalculateFull` method seems to rebuild that.

More can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#all-open-workbooks-tree-rebuild-and-forced-calculation

I have taken a look at the calculation trees of before the formulas seem to stop calculating and after (when they become stale), and they trees seem to differ, even though they are the same file. So something has changed how Excel has decided to save that calculation tree.

I have also found that by setting `Worksheet.EnableCalculation = False` and then setting it back to `Worksheet.EnableCalculation = True`, seems to reset the calculation tree and the workbook calculates fine after.

Does anyone know more about how the calculation tree is built, and what causes it to break, possibly citing references as well? It seems difficult to research this via Google.

Comment: Cells are recalculated when either the formula text itself changes or when the content of dependent cells changes. If a cell depends on other data (that Excel doesn't see), it is not recalculated except if you use a function that is declared as volatile - that signals to Excel that this value should be recalculated anyhow.

Comment: Indeed, but in this instance, for example, if I use a function called `GetUsername`, when a different user opens the worksheet one would think it would refresh due to the change in the name of the user. But for some reason it is not even calculating the cell with a Shift+F9 on the worksheet.

Comment: @chrisneilsen and @FunThomas to confirm these are not custom VBA UDF, where I can use `Application.Volatile` to force them. This is a C# add-in which does not expose that ability.

Comment: To be clear, what Funthomas is describing  means that to guarantee a non Volatile function recalculated, it's inputs must reference _all_ cells that might affect its output

Comment: If you're saying the output depends on a property not contained in a cell, then you're out of luck.  Volatility is the only way to guarantee recalculation

Comment: @Dean: No, that's exactly the point: Excel doesn't check that the username was changed - username is not an Excel object. Excel only checks if dependent cells changed.

Comment: @FunThomas understood - however, why would this behaviour appear random? I would accept your POV if it was ALWAYS the case, however, it is only SOMETIMES. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: And this is the point of the question. The functions are not loading SOMETIMES. Based on your above arguments, they should NEVER re-calculate. But this is not the case. There is something else that is preventing them from re-calculating.

Comment: Supposing that all calculations could be reduced to a value (or more) that start them all, then they also could be related to other cells, to be changed by the user to initiate the function. Wouldn't this be enough to start a forced re-computation of the whole workbook?

Comment: This is not an uncommon problem when creating addins that maintain "state": the addin doesn't know if/when to recalculate the function. One workaround that is used is to add a dummy variable to the function, and use this to control recalculation. In this particular example, you could add a workbook open macro to call `Application.CalculateFull` which would re-calc everything in the open session.

Comment: "This is a C# add-in which does not expose that ability." It is a while since I did this (a long while) but I did find a way to specify that a C# addin function is volatile. As I recall, it involved getting a COM pointer to the Excel Application object, and setting Volatile on that. The Excel DNA package for C# addins has a method I believe.

Comment: @DS_London after some more research, it seems that Excel's calculation tree seems to break, and so [the `.CalculateFull` method seems to rebuild that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#all-open-workbooks-tree-rebuild-and-forced-calculation). In my situation, it is not efficient to do this as it takes an extremely long time to calculate. Do you know how/why the calculation tree breaks?